# How i can disable minutes input in angular ui Timepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

This plugin displays time (hours and minutes). I need hours only. How i can hide minutes block?

My html:

```
 <uib-timepicker ng-model="mytime" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="1" minute-step="10" show-meridian="false" readonly-input="true"></uib-timepicker>
```

Controller.js:

```
$scope.mytime = new Date();
```

Comment: Either change the template html in uib-timepicker component or override it with your own modified version of the template.
See [link](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/timepicker/timepicker.html) for the timepicker template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use readonly-input="true" for time picker and set minute-step="0". It will disable your minute input.

If you do not like the look and feel of the read only timepicker, you can change the template URL and add one of your own in timepicker tag itself.

```
template-url = "templates/customTemplate.html"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override the default timepicker template by setting a `template-url` in the directive:

```
 <uib-timepicker ng-model="mytime" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="1" minute-step="10" show-meridian="false" template-url="urlOfYourModifiedTimepicker.html" readonly-input="true"></uib-timepicker>
```

You can get the default template from [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/timepicker/timepicker.html), and remove the minutes and seconds elements. Store this modified template in your project and set the url of this template in your directive `template-url="urlToYourModifiedTemplate.html"

Hope this will help you out.